# Creating an MSI installer for a C# SCD Deployment (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: .net-core, deployment, windows-installer

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application that I'd like to deploy as a Self Contained (SCD) Deployment using an MSI Installer in Visual Studio 2019...

I have published the project as an SCD Deployment and I can run this on the target machine just fine

However, I've been asked by IT support to provide an MSI installer for the application as .MSI files work well with some of the admin/control applications they have.

So I created a setup project in my solution and selected 'Publish Items' as the Project Output of the setup project and rebuilt it...

The installer seems to run just fine on the target machine but when we try to run the installed application it says that .Net Core is required ...It's as if the installer has ignored the Self Contained aspect and just installed as a regular Framework Dependent Deployment

Is there a way to create an installer that installs an SCD deployment?  Have I made a mistake in my thinking?

Many Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

The VS Setup Project template is quite old. Most likely it was not updated to be "aware" of the SCD support so it resorts to extracting the classic output binaries from your project.

There are other free tools that you can use to create an MSI from VS, which give you more options to customize and correctly configure the package.

If you have time and want to learn a new skill, try [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/). It is very powerful but you will need some time to get started.

If you wanted to get it done quickly and avoid the hassle, use the free [VS Extension from Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html#section739). Its GUI allows you to easily create your setup package and it has native support for .NET Core packaging too. If you follow the steps from the linked tutorial it should create a working package for your application.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bogdan + makes sense ...I'll take a look at those options